# Looping through numbers from 1 to 100 and for every 10 numbers save the number divide by 10

Tags: php

This code is do what i want, but i think there is a better enchantment
that could do this code in a few lines specifically if the loop will be from 1 to 1000

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) 
{
    if ($i <= 10 ) {
        $id = 1;
    }
    elseif ($i > 10 && $i <= 20) {
        $id = 2;
    }
    elseif ($i > 20 && $i <= 30) {
        $id = 3;
    }
    elseif ($i > 30 && $i <= 40) {
        $id = 4;
    }
    elseif ($i > 40 && $i <= 50) {
        $id = 5;
    }
    elseif ($i > 50 && $i <= 60) {
        $id = 6;
    }
    elseif ($i > 60 && $i <= 70) {
        $id = 7;
    }
    elseif ($i > 70 && $i <= 80) {
        $id = 8;
    }
    elseif ($i > 80 && $i <= 90) {
        $id = 9;
    }
    elseif ($i > 90 ) {
        $id = 10;
    }

    $array = ['id' => $id, 'order' => $i];

    Provider::create($array);
}
```

Comment: Understanding what the [modulo operator (`%`)](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) does would help

Comment: PS. Nothing whatsoever to do with `Laravel` as you've tagged; this is all about basic `PHP` (with a little bit of `mathematics` for good measure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 1000; $i++) 
{
    $id = ceil($i/10);
    $array = ['id' => $id, 'order' => $i];

    Provider::create($array);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i want , Thanks :)

Comment: Your forget to add ; at the end of  $id = ceil($i/10);

Comment: Opsssss! Semicolon (;) added

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) 
{
    $id = $i/10;
    if ($i%10 == 0) {
      echo "id: ".$id." Order: ".$i."\n";
      $arr[$id] = $i;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

**Output**

```
id: 1 Order: 10
id: 2 Order: 20
id: 3 Order: 30
id: 4 Order: 40
id: 5 Order: 50
id: 6 Order: 60
id: 7 Order: 70
id: 8 Order: 80
id: 9 Order: 90
id: 10 Order: 100
Array
(
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 30
    [4] => 40
    [5] => 50
    [6] => 60
    [7] => 70
    [8] => 80
    [9] => 90
    [10] => 100
)
```

**Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/819917)**

Comment: Check above code and let me know if any further issue. @Ahmed Al Bermawy